# Arrows/images between bootstrap columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 images within a row. Between each column, i'd like to add an arrow pointing to the next image.

How can I do this, while keep the existing images centered (so the middle one is in the middle of the page), and so it degrades nicely on smaller screens (disappears for instance)?

html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                        <h1 class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: center;">EASY TO USE</h1>
                        <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <img class="img" src="../assets/img/indevice/step1htc.mini.24.png" height="350px" width="240px" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="img col-sm-1"><img class="img" src="../assets/img/arrow.png" alt=""></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <img class="img" src="../assets/img/indevice/step2htc.mini.24.png" height="350px" width="240px" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="img col-sm-1"><img class="img" src="../assets//img/arrow.png" alt=""></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <img class="img" src="../assets/img/indevice/step3htc.mini.24.png" height="350px" width="240px" alt="">
                                </div>
                </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: For clarification, I want to add arrows between the existing images in the html code above. The html/css above is already centered. Howver, i'd like to *add* 2 arrows between the 3 existing images.

EDIT: Please see this image to understand what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHAIf.jpg

EDIT: Changed html to show a full example, including css call.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <h1 class="centered" style="text-align: center;">EASY TO USE</h1>
         <hr>
         <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left:4.17%;">
            <img class="img" src="image" height="350px" width="240px" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="img col-md-1">
            <img class="img" src="../assets/img/arrow.png" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <img class="img" src="image" height="350px" width="240px" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="img col-md-1">
            <img class="img" src="../assets//img/arrow.png" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <img class="img" src="image" height="350px" width="240px" alt="">
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

All i did is removed the extra col-md-1 class and instead added  the margin of the same equivalance to the 1st element so that it stay in the center.

Comment: Please see my clarification. If you need further clarification, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: But this is not centered... http://imgur.com/QyZPl3b. Further, to work, I changed it to `<div class="img col-sm-1"><img class="img" src="arrow.png" alt=""></div>`

Comment: changing to div should not make any difference. I want to know what do you want to center allign to ? The entire screen or just the middle image ?

Comment: It did. I don't understand your last sentence. I want the middle column, the middle image, to remain centered /aligned with everything else on the page.

Comment: Yes I did. I had even tried that prior to posting the question.

Comment: You can see the barebones html here: http://www.bootply.com/130197#. I've also edited my question.

Comment: But why is that hack necessary?

Comment: I tried out your code, and if you resize the browser window, it doesn't stay centrally aligned. http://www.bootply.com/130795

Comment: Where did you add the code for making it responsive ? 
you need to add cols-sm-* for the smaller screen resolution.
The hack is necessary coz the entire grid does not make up to 12 cols. So the last column left is adjusted this way : (100 / 12) / 2

Comment: huh? I don't understand that comment. I've already replaced with *md* with *sm*. More importantly, did you try before commenting?

Comment: Please refer to bootstrap before commenting. You need to add sm & md both if you need to implement responsiveness. You yourself updated the  code and that was working. If you  have anything else then better you raise a new question

Comment: Please refrain from ever commenting on any of my questions in the future. You've been extremely unhelpful, and incredibly frustrating to communicate with.

Comment: You need to be specific in your question brother. This is not the way people answer here. All right i will refrain answering your questions.